# Why hasn't my bitcoin transaction gone through?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, confirmations

So about 3hrs from now I made a transaction to a different wallet of mine and the money didnt come through in 20mins I checked the blockchain and the number of confirmations kept rising and its up to 13, why is that? How long it can take?

Comment: What wallet are you using? Is it up-to-date, i.e. synchronized with the network?

Comment: Im using an official wallet where I originally bought the btc and trying to transfer to a mixer wallet, atm its 64 confirmations

Comment: @Vytautasbrah it doesn't matter about confirmations if we don't know the exact details of your wallet, and preferably OS (Windows? Mac?).

Comment: `trying to transfer to a mixer wallet` You mean a mixer service, I'm assuming. If this is the case then you don't own the private keys to the interim addresses, so you cannot be certain this mixer service has not stolen your funds, which is highly probable. EDIT: Now that I think of it, you'll need to clarify whether the other wallet you're talking about is a virtual wallet with the mixing service

Comment: OS is android. I can log in to both wallets no problem . Its an virtual wallet with a mixing service. Then what other ways can I mix my bitcoins what wallets/mixers I can trust and/if you guys are using one how do you do it to recieve the funds? (Name of the mixing servise and a few simple steps would be really appreciated). And thanks for the replies its nice to see that my question is not just ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You've sent Bitcoins like so:

`WALLET1 ==> mixer ==> WALLET2`

The problem here is that you can't be certain the middle part will work, be it for technical reasons, or more likely, they've been lost or "lost". By nature, mixers are run for clientele operating in the "very dark grey area". So it's extremely unlikely you've got any recourse, other than contacting their tech support. I'm sure you know all this.

Fundamentally, mixers in charge of your funds cannot be trusted. Theoretically, the only way I can see around this would be for a service to pre-mix the required amount, and then for you to withdraw it after you know it's safe, which would likely need to use BIP65 and/or BIP16, or perhaps a combination therein with message signing, to prove address ownership. I don't know there's any mixers like this, because quite frankly, I believe their profits come moreso from scamming or selectively scamming.

Because mixers are out, your options are either CoinJoin or DarkWallet, but I have not got experience with either of them.

This probably isn't the answer you're looking for, but unfortunately this is where it stands. Good luck.